# A equality of convolutions

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, distribution-theory, convolution

Is the following equality of convolutions True?

$1*h_\alpha*\Delta u(x)=g_\alpha*\Delta u(x), \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n. $

Where $h_\alpha (t)=g'(t)$ and $g(t)=t^{\alpha-1}/\Gamma(\alpha+1)$, $t>0$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$. The function $u:[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is sufficiently smooth. I am trying prove replacing $\Delta u$ for a $C^\infty$ with compact suport function $\phi$, but i cant arrive anywhere. Futhermore, dont want prove to the distribution sense.

Comment: There are different definitions of [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition) . If you use the one for functions supported only on $[0,\infty)$ it is trivial that $(1*h)(t)=(h*1)(t)=\int_0^tg'(s)ds=g(t)$ which yields your equality without further assumptions.

Comment: @KurtG. $\int_0^t g'(s)ds=g(t)-g(0)$ but $g(t)$ isn't continuous on $s=0$.

Comment: Right. The minimal assumption on $g'$ is that it should be integrable. Is that the case for your $g(t)\sim t^{\alpha-1}$ ? If not does that answer the question if that convolution equality is true ?